# Recreate http.Request persisted by Request.Write

Tags: go

I have a `http.Request` which I wrote to a file using `Request.Write`. Since there is no `Request.Read` or similar, I was wondering how I can recreate a `http.Request` using the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`http.ReadRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadRequest).